# Добавление собственного языка для перевода в Django

Tags: python, django

Надо сделать на сайте перевод на башкирский язык. Такого вроде нет в файле `locale` django.
Пробую сделать так. В файле settings.py добавил

```
import django.conf.locale
EXTRA_LANG_INFO = {
    'ba': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'ba',
        'name': 'Bashkir',
        'name_local': 'башкирский'
    },
}
d = django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO.copy()
d.update(EXTRA_LANG_INFO)
django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO = d


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru' 

LANGUAGES = (
  ('ru', 'Russian'),
  ('en','English'),
  ('ba', 'Bashkir'),
)
```

теперь при переходе по ссылке в пишет что не может найти страницу `/ba`.(при этом на en и ru версию переходит без проблем).
ссылки на странице вывожу так:

```
{% for language in languages %}                         
     <a href="/{{ language.code }}/"}>{{ language.code }} </a>
{% endfor %}
```

в `urls` `+= i18n_patterns` добавил .
Может есть ещё какой-то способ, подскажите где посмотреть, а то не нашел вообще инфы по этой теме.

Comment: Покажите urls .

Comment: Кроме того, убедитесь, что вы не путаете `/ba` и `/ba/`

Comment: @andreymal ну там просто `urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('', include('registers.urls')),
)` когда делал с английским так работало. А сейчас ты принципе при переходе ( когда пишет что страница не найдена) там в списке нет юрл с ba. Только ру